# Change site from HTML to React based on Next.js 14

Tags: html, css, web, next.js

my current page is hosted on hosting, and the page is pure html,css,js.
I created a React version of this website and deployed it on Vercel.
Now I wanted to put it on my main server, however after `npm run build` it didnt include cs,js and the code was messy.

My idea is to create a redirect so every time a user enters my website [www.auto-s.pl](http://www.auto-s.pl) is automatically redirected to autos-react.vercel.app.

My only consern is **Google Indexing** and search engine optimalization. How to make sure that it indexes the old page and not the new one? I want everywhere to be seen the old url the auto-s.pl and not the new one, but in the same time i want users to be redirected to a new page.

I tried to give a vercel deployment a custom domain name, but i am afraid of the google search optimalization issues. What should i do?
My current website: https://auto-s.pl and the Vercel one: https://autos-react.vercel.app/